# App getting crashed whenever i am receiving the notification

Tags: android

Recently i got the error in ANR & Crashes in Google Playstore. After that i tried to simulate the issue and got the issue and simulated now in my device. But my concern like where i want to fix it. Because here i am not getting any files which i developed.

Following error i am getting whenever receive the gcm notification in android. Any one face this issue and resolve it before. Its a debug build.

Thanks in advance. Pls help.

**Error :**

```
07-26 15:18:16.780 163-163/? E/MNLD: launch_daemon_thread: Before main policy = 0, priority = 0
07-26 15:18:16.782 163-163/? E/MNLD: launch_daemon_thread: pthread_setschedparam FAIL 
07-26 15:18:17.199 18544-18805/com.bharatmatrimony A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x782f7988 in tid 18805 (pool-3-thread-1)
07-26 15:18:17.223 657-657/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
07-26 15:18:17.240 657-657/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$TextViewDrawableAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1502)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1373)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.inflateViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1332)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1762)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1201)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:489)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-26 15:18:17.256 657-657/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
07-26 15:18:17.257 657-657/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$TextViewDrawableAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1502)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1373)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2804)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.inflateViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1338)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1762)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1201)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:489)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-26 15:18:17.273 1166-1166/? W/ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
07-26 15:18:17.301 17994-17994/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'google/AQ4502/AQ4502_sprout:6.0.1/MOB30Q/2975880:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 18544, tid: 18805, name: pool-3-thread-1  >>> com.bharatmatrimony <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x782f7988
07-26 15:18:17.316 17994-17994/? A/DEBUG:     r0 782f7974  r1 1af23480  r2 70c51a50  r3 b7d992a0
07-26 15:18:17.317 17994-17994/? A/DEBUG:     r4 b4e47920  r5 fffff7b0  r6 70c51a50  r7 782f7974
        r8 b7d992a0  r9 b7d992a0  sl 70ac58d0  fp b6d18e40
        ip a3283b60  sp a3283a40  lr b4ae2d7d  pc b4de2c38  cpsr 000e0030
07-26 15:18:17.322 17994-17994/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 003e5c38  /system/lib/libart.so (artInvokeInterfaceTrampoline+27)
        #01 pc 000e5d79  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_interface_trampoline+40)
        #02 pc 72befaf7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ec9000)
```

Comment: Where is your Code?

Comment: which file i want to share?... Because i made a project and taken into the playstore and working for next version.

Comment: share your targetSdkVersion and notification receiving class

Comment: TargetSdkVersion : 26; Class file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_SJgp3-k6jb01Gc7N3pQmPydHQB2stI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i can't able to download.. edit your question

Comment: I cant able to post the whole code. Its downloadable only. i cross checked.